# PIC32MZ DA chip programs successfully but does not respond

Tags: pic

I got a hardware debug kind of situation here. I have a board that is designed to have the PIC32MZ2025DAR176 chip on it and have been having issues trying to get it up and running, namely, I can get the device to program but it otherwise does not seem to turn on, which is surprising to me.

I have checked MCLR to see it during the ON state and I see 3.3V, so I don't think a reset is happening. I checked with a DMM to look for shorts between pins by probing the leads carefully, didn't see any. I have a crystal clock onboard but am attempting to startup using the FRC. My code project is generated with the MPLABX Code Configurator just for some pinout definitions, my test program is merely supposed to toggle a pin leading to an LED + resistor (test point 1) and output high on another trace (test point 2) where the other end is left floating for now.

I have probed my circuit to diagnose what is going on and here is some odd behavior.
Using a DMM to probe the lines, I get a reading of 0V when measuring the test point 2 against ground, but I also get the same reading when measuring the test point against VCC... so the test point is actually left floating by the microcontroller, isn't it? Probing test point 1 (at the positive end of the resistor, which is in place before the LED) shows 0V between the point and GND, but 1.8V when measuring either end of the resistor against 3.3V (resistor is at lower voltage). When I measure over the resistor + LED combo, I see 0V.

I have verified the 3.3V and 1.8V supplies coming from the regulators I have on board, a DC Power supply is delivering 5V power to the regs and the meter shows 0.07 A being drawn in the ON state. My specific questions are these:

1. If a PIC device programs successfully, is there still possibility that it might not be powering up correctly? I ask because I know decoupling and power delivery was important for these devices, lots of power pins.
2. Are there any configuration settings that might cause some sort of shutdown condition like this I could check? I verified that watchdog is not being used, used the pin settings to select digital, etc etc. I recently programmed a board based around a PIC32MK and MCC and didn't have any issues like this but haven't used MCC a ton otherwise maybe there is something I have missed.
3. Is there something I can do while my device is connected via a Pickit 4 programmer to talk with the PIC32 to see if it is functioning correctly if a successful programming does not guarantee working and awake device?
4. Do you have any other ideas for what I could try to diagnose the circuit or what to look at?

Thanks for any advice you can offer!

Comment: If you have DDR enabled, do you have a midref supply? Also, maybe your oscillator isnt working.

Comment: Shucks... no I do not have the midref supply, I see it now... I can't believe I missed that. I believe I can fix that via the two 2k resistor divider method, fixing it now. I switched the oscillator to the internal FRC, so I would hope that would allow it to at least boot up right?

Comment: Without the midref the CPU hangs or something per my experience, at least with harmony enabling DDR.

Comment: It seems that the INTVREFCON bits determine the source for DDRVREF and if you enable internal DDRVREF, it will drive the pin to VDDR1V8/2... any thoughts on using that? I added the resistor divider but no luck yet. I am reading that other people on the MPLAB forums have said they needed a larger cap on VCore to address needing a slower rise time during powering on, I wonder if the chip is really that sensitive?

Comment: I don't know, my experience is with the dah, it has errata regarding midref, have you looked at the datasheet and/or the reference designs to see what they are doing? If you don't enable DDR in code and it runs, then you'll know of that's the issue. You can track where is stops with the debugger too.

Comment: Also think about this, if you try to access DDR memory and the controller isn't ready, it'll probably crash the MCU.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, and I am seeing in the curiosity board that they use two series resistors of 1.8K value, they decouple the voltage feeding into the pin. I believe I had the DDR disabled as I have not activated it in MCC or have any custom code to access it, is there a specific bit to disable it? I noticed in the clocking diagram that the memory PLL only feeds from the POSC… so that Crystal needs to work and I am not seeing any activity on the CLKI/CLKO pins. I’m off to try the debugging mode.

Comment: Update: by turning off the MPLL via the MPLLDIS bit, the chip seems to have come to life, my test LED is blinking. Does this mean that the DDR module is shot (I was sending 1.8V into the DDRVREF pin previously) or do I need to have all the MCC elements setup before enabling the MPLL?